# Hypothesis Testing on Exponential distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, exponential-distribution, self-study, exponential-family, rejection-sampling

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be independent exponential $(\theta)$ random variables. Suppose we are interested in testing $H_0: \theta = \theta_0 = 1$ versus $H_A: \theta = \theta_1>1$. Consider two tests with rejection regions:

Test 1: {$ (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum^n_{j=1} x_j \geq k_{\alpha}$},

Test 2: {$ (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n: X_{(1)} \geq h_{\alpha}$}.

> (1) For $n = 10$ and $\alpha = 0.05$, calculate $k_{\alpha}$.

$\bf{My \ thoughts:}$ I know I need to set if up so I find the distribution of $\sum^n_{j=1} x_j $.  Not quite sure on setting it up to get a value so I have it equal to the $\alpha$ given.

> (2) For $n = 10$ and $\alpha = 0.05$, calculate $h_{\alpha}$.

$\bf{My \ thoughts:}$  Same idea as number (1), but again I am stuck on proper set-up.

> (3) Using the values found for $k_{\alpha}$ and $h_{\alpha}$, calculate the power of both tests with $\theta =2, 3, 4$. Based on the results of these findings, which test should be used?

$\bf{My \ thoughts:}$  I think this may require a bit more work but I will just need to set it up according to the cases of the values for $\theta$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: An Exponential variate is [Gamma(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Summation); Gamma variates enjoy nice relationships under addition.

Comment: Hi user45185. You seem to be posting a lot of 'bookwork' . If this is for some subject, or just for self-study, would you mind adding the 'self-study' tag to the ones that don't have it yet, please?

Comment: Can you explain why the first one is in terms of sample values ($x$) while the second seems to be in terms of random variables ($X$)?  On (2), note that $P(X_{(1)} \leq x) = P(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n \leq x)$. Can you do it now? Try that first (it's easy!), or failing that, [see this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables) and then try the hint again.

Comment: Thanks. I made that correction.  This is actually for a course of study.  I am sorry for the notation.  I copied it as it was written and it may not be totally accurate.